# Best way to ensure that a child package fails with any error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

What is the best way to ensure a child package fails if the main data flow in it fails, if it encounters any error ?

I was thinking of the OnTaskFailed Event handler , that has the main data flow (Task 1 ) and an execute sql task ( Task 2) to write to a table that the event has failed. Is it as easy as that or is there anything else that needs to be set up ?

Comment: This depends on what you mean by fail. TRUNCATION and Inserts can fail on their own (such as SQL server running into a fatal error), so explain a little more, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best done through an event handler on the data flow